# JabRef - Can't use ISBN to Bibtex-feature anymore, windows just closes

Tags: jabref

After I recently did a drag & drop action with several PDF files and let JabRef auto-import their properties/details, I noticed the ISBN to Bibtex-feature stopped working. If I enter (via c&p, of course) any ISBN into the field and hit enter, the result windows pops up for a moment and closes immediately after. Nothing happens, no import, no new entry whatsoever.

Would anyone have a clue as to what could be done to fix this?

If it helps: Windows 7 64 bit, JabRef 2.10.

*Note:* I am only posting this because I haven't received [a reply on the official JabRef forums yet](https://sourceforge.net/p/jabref/discussion/318825/thread/c43b36cb/?limit=25).

Comment: I think this is best addressed at the JabRef site. It does not seem related to any constraint/feature in regards of TeX. As such I think this is off-topic.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken they are using a third-party script for this functionality and probably that one is broken.

Comment: @percusse Apparently it is some sort of "relatively" simple feature to use a website to search for a ISBN, more [here](http://jabref.sourceforge.net/help/ISBNtoBibTeXHelp.php).